# Is there a name for a quantity that represents (volumetric) flow per unit of mass?

Tags: units, si-units, flow, medical-physics

In a lot of medical literature about blood flow in the brain, researchers denote the amount of volumetric blood flow that passes through a certain amount of brain tissue as "cerebral blood flow". However, its associated unit is volumetric flow *per unit of mass*, e.g. 50 mililiters per minute per 100 grams of brain tissue.

However, I don't want to mix up actual volumetric flow (e.g. in mililiters per minute) with this volumetric flow per mass. Can you suggest a name for the latter quantity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "specific" (as in specific gravity or specific heat capacity) means per unit mass, so you could call it "specific flow" or "specific volumetric flow".